# how to pass list string from view to controller by ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

this is my html

```
<ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display:none;">
                    <li class="sb_filter">Chon the loai</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="All"/><label for="all"><strong>Tất cả</strong></label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Woman"/><label for="Automotive">Đồ nữ</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Shoes"/><label for="Baby">Giày</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Bag"/><label for="Beauty">Túi sách</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Man"/><label for="Books">Đồ nam</label></li>                      
                </ul>
```

this is my ajax to call control,

```
 <script>
                        $('.sb_search').click(function () {
                            var list = [];
                            $('ul.sb_dropdown').find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                                list.push($(this).val());
                            });
                            var key = { listkey: list };
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Result")',
                                traditional: true,
                                data: list,
                                dataType: "html",
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("success");
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert("fail");
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    </script>
```

In my controller,i have a paramater listkey that i hope will receive from view when i click button search

```
public ActionResult Result()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Result(List<string> listkey)
    {
        var n = listkey;
        return View();
    }
```

when i debug this isn't do the action result,and it alert fail.tell me what im doing wrong.and please help me about returnjson why i need to use instead i want to use normal View to show my result

I has been solved this problem because i put wrong action and controller in my ajax.Thank you all

Comment: Why you want to pass your html to the `action result`? Instead you can pass only the values which is `selected/un-selected`.

Comment: i dont want to pass my html to action result,i want to pass a list value of checkbox where its checked,and i want to open a view of result in search controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit try this , create array and pass that to your controller

```
    var stringArray = new Array();
    stringArray[0] = "item1";
    stringArray[1] = "item2";
    stringArray[2] = "item3";
    var postData = { listkey: stringArray };
```

than you data will be , in you ajax call

```
   data: postData 


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Result")',
        data: postData,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
```

---

you can do like this ,

1. convert you list into json string like as below

you data will be   `data: '{ "listkey":' + JSON.stringify(list) + '}',`

```
$.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Result")',
                                traditional: true,
                                 data: '{ "listkey":' + JSON.stringify(list) + '}',
                                dataType: "html",
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("success");
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert("fail");
                                }
                            });
```

than try to see you are getting result you want or not

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Result(List<string> listkey)
        {
            var n = listkey;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Its not getting the paramater listkey to my controller when i debug,i think i right when i use ajax to call a action,and pass paramater to its.i dont see any fault on this code

Comment: hi prana,i try this and it doesn't work agian.So i do it in the Layout page, i was try to easy change paramater to int id,and i pass it with value 1,it alert fail

Comment: @CongLe - pelase do accept answer if it is help you to resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $('.sb_search').click(function () {
    var list = [];
    $('ul.sb_dropdown').find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    list.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Result")',
        data: { listkey: list },
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
});
 </script>



       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Result(List<string> listkey)
       {
           var n = listkey;
           return View();
       }
```